# How to manually set finbuckle current tenant for integration testing

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing, multi-tenant

I am trying to "integration test" a multi-tenant dotnet core application, since repositories and DbContexts requires the current tenant information which is normally set using the Mediator during requests.

In integration test I need to set the tenant manually,
I have tried to create httpcontext object and use the TrySetTenantInfo function but it gives error

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

here is the code I tried for httpcontext setting

```
_httpContextAccessor =_servicesProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();

TenantInfo ti = new TenantInfo
        {
            Id = "**",
            Identifier = "**",
            ConnectionString = "**",
            Name = "***"
        };
//here is the error thrown 
        if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.TrySetTenantInfo(ti, true))
        {
        
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: You need default tenant or set predefined tenant... Question may be one of this. I guess